# Setting playbackRate on audio element connected to web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've been experimenting with connecting an audio element to the web audio api using createMediaElementSource and got it to work but one thing I need to do is change the playback rate of the audio tag and I couldn't get that to work.

If you try to run the code below, you'll see that it works until you uncomment the line where we set the playback rate. When this line is in the audio gets muted.

I know I can set the playback rate on an AudioBufferSourceNode using source.playbackRate.value but this is not what I'd like to do, I need to set the playback rate on the audio element while it's connected to the web audio api using createMediaElementSource so I don't have any AudioBufferSourceNode.

Has anyone managed to do that?

```
var _source,
     _audio,
     _context,
     _gainNode;

_context = new webkitAudioContext();

function play(url) {
    if (_audio) {
        _audio.pause();
    }
    _audio = new Audio(url);
    //_audio.playbackRate = 0.6;

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!_gainNode) {
            _gainNode = _context.createGainNode();
            _gainNode.gain.value = 0.1;
            _gainNode.connect(_context.destination);
        }

        _source = _context.createMediaElementSource(_audio);
        _source.connect(_gainNode);

        _audio.play();
    }, 0);

}

play("http://geo-samples.beatport.com/items/volumes/volume2/items/3000000/200000/40000/9000/400/60/3249465.LOFI.mp3");

setTimeout(function () {
    _audio.pause();
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Odd, this seems to work for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9gLKM/
--

Chrome: Version 22.0.1229.94 m

Comment: This is still an issue in Safari (at least v13.0.0, but perhaps earlier); Chrome/Firefox work fine. upon hooking up [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) nodes, the volume and playbackRate can no longer be set on the [audio tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). For volume, connect a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) and, as you have already mentioned, for playbackRate, connect a [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode).

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the playback rate *after* the audio has started playing. The only portable way I have found to make this work, is by waiting until you get a `timeupdate` event with valid `currentTime`:

```
_audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    _if(!isNaN(audio.currentTime)) {
        _audio.playbackRate = 0.6;
    }
});
```

Note that playback rate isn't currently supported on android and that Chrome (on desktop) doesn't support playback rates lower than 0.5.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Where in the spec does it specify that an audio's playback rate cannot be set until after initial playback?

Comment: As I read the spec (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-playbackrate), the intention is that the ``defaultPlaybackRate`` will (re)set the ``playbackRate`` as soon as playback starts. After this, the playback rate can dynamically be set using ``playbackRate``. Having to do it as I wrote above is a little weird, but alas - it is the only thing that works. Trust me :) (I am the current author of https://github.com/Notalib/LYT and have spent about 40 hours on this issue alone.)

Comment: What about setting [`defaultPlaybackRate`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-defaultplaybackrate)?

Comment: I'm not saying you're incorrect about having to set it after playback. I just don't understand *why* that's the case. The browser should be able to abstract that requirement away and the spec should put the responsibility on the browser vendors.

Comment: The specification mentions that the browser can expose visual controls to the user, where the browser *may* let the user change the playback rate. First off, making it possible to let the browser expose a browser-specific control interface is a really bad idea, but that's how the spec is phrased. I think that the interaction with this interface dictates the need to have both ``playbackRate`` and ``defaultPlaybackRate``.

Comment: I haven't experimented too much with ``defaultPlaybackRate``, but as I remember it, some browsers simply don't support this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you using to test this? It seems this is not yet implemented in Firefox, but should be working on Chrome.

Mozilla bug for implementing playbackRate:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=495040

Comment: I'm using chrome. Firefox supports the audio tag but doesn't support the web audio api and my code uses both technologies so this wouldn't run on firefox.

Comment: In chrome the playbackRate does work on a standalone audio tag but what I'm trying to do is make it work on an audio element that is connected to the web audio api using createMediaElementSource. That's the part that I couldn't get working.