# <video>.playbackRate not working on firefox when using HTMLMediaElementSourceNode

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, web-audio-api

As stated in the title, I have been running in an issue regarding the HTMLVideoElement when connected to the WebAudioAPI inside Firefox.

The following sample gives a minimal example reproducing the issue:

```
var video      = document.getElementById('video');
var ctx        = new AudioContext();
var sourceNode = ctx.createMediaElementSource(video);
sourceNode.connect(ctx.destination);
video.playbackRate = 3;
video.play();
```

As soon as the video element is connected to the audio pipeline, I cannot get the playbackRate setter to work anymore.
I've been looking for a way to set this value somewhere inside the AudioContext or the HTMLMediaElementSourceNode objects but those classes do not seem to handle playback-rate on their own.

Please note that this sample works fine on Chrome. And I don't really see what seems to be the problem here.

Thanks

Comment: Confirmed on nighty 50.0a1 on mac os. Unfortunately, we can't tell you more than "*Fill a bug in [Mozilla's BugZilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) if there isn't one already.*". Oh and the same happens for audio element

Comment: My bad, should have checked this before:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966247

Comment: yep and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239757/setting-playbackrate-on-audio-element-connected-to-web-audio-api Vote for the bug!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already reported over the Firefox's bug tracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966247